# Ember CLI and Google Analytics

Tags: ember.js

According to the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/), you just need to embed the analytics code and reopen the Router.  The latter seems unclear to me.

I've placed the embedded code on `index.html`, then created the following

`app/reopens/router.js`

```
import Router from '../router';

Router.reopen({
  notifyGoogleAnalytics: function() {
    return ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'page': this.get('url'),
      'title': this.get('url')
    });
  }.on('didTransition')
});
```

`app/app.js`: Added the import...

```
import './reopens/router';
```

This results in a fatal error when viewing the site: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

How do you make the `ga` function visible to this observer?

Comment: it should be globally available before ember script runs, instead you can use this addon https://github.com/pgrippi/ember-cli-google-analytics

Comment: Did you include the google analytics tracking snippet in your index.html? See the image on http://mashable.com/2011/05/23/how-to-use-google-analytics/#cLeb78UHUSq3

Comment: It's now 2016 and I'm facing the same error after following the [Ember analytics guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/) but apparently [Google's ga is a legacy library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) although I now have the latest code. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: @DaveEveritt Please share what you find here.  My project was on hold, but I'll be diving back into it tonight/tomorrow

Comment: It requires the requirements in the browser messages to be added to the suitable Content Security blocks in the config file. Even then I couldn't make the errors go away so my co-dev has taken over.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that on the first run through of the didTransition, the method is missing as that part of the script has not been executed.

Is this a problem? Actually no. The purpose of didTransition in this instance is to capture when a transition occurs as the supplied javascript from Google with capture to initial local of the page. All is needed is a check to see if 'ga' exists.

1. Add the recommended javascript to the index.html of your ember app from Google (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/).
2. Modify your code to include a check to see if ga is undefined:

   ```
   import Router from '../router';

   Router.reopen({
       notifyGoogleAnalytics: function() {
           if (typeof ga != 'function') { return; }
           return ga('send', 'pageview', {
             'page': this.get('url'),
             'title': this.get('url')
           });
       }.on('didTransition')
   });
   ```

This is variation of what I have for an ember-cli based app. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This is the proper response, however, I want to add that for all transitions, you should be setting the page variable as well so that all events get updated so that you can know what page they were fired on.

For instance, the addon I wrote [ember-tracker](https://github.com/tsteuwer/ember-tracker) sets the page before sending the `pageview` event. You can see it here: https://github.com/tsteuwer/ember-tracker/blob/master/addon/services/google-analytics.js#L124

Answer (score 0):

After looking, exhaustively, for a way to plug Google Analytics into Ember, I built my own. For all those still struggling with this issue and not finding the Ember.js v1.0.0 answer helpful, here is how I got it to work on v4.2:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ApplicationRoute extends Route {
  @action
  didTransition() {
    gtag('set', 'page_path', window.location.pathname);
    gtag('event', 'page_view');

    return true;
  }
}
```

Forgive my ignorance, as I am new to Ember, but the existing documentation makes it look like didTransition is no longer supported at the router level. That makes +99% of the solutions I found on the internet outdated.

Instead, I invoked didTransition at the route level. By extending Route as ApplicationRoute, I extended the main behavior of every Route. In this example, I execute the gtag event for triggering a page view after setting the page URL. The gtag code from Google simply goes in the index.html file in the head section.

Hopefully, this saves someone from hours of searching.